# How to distinguish between "using declaration" and "using directive" in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I distinguish between "using-declaration" and "using directive" in C++? What are the main differences between "using-declaration" and "using directive"? Could somebody make it clear by giving some simple examples? I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As description in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using

> using-directives for namespaces and using-declarations for namespace members

```
using namespace std; // using-directive   
using std::string;   // using-declaration
```